# Error: Tezos_stdlib__Lwt_pipe.Closed for "ideal front node configuration"

Tags: node, baker, error

**Situation:**

I am using the following configuration for my front node:

[image: Luke's message concerning front node configuration from slack.]

The intention is to have as many connections worldwide in order to be sure to bake a block that is accepted because it included all transactions from the *mempool* and propagates the block to the right nodes.

Problem:

I am getting the following error very often:

```
Mar  1 16:42:24 - p2p.connection: error writing to idtmJFgQZ4tjGQSD2eoGdL4WGZwASw  
Mar  1 16:42:24 - p2p.connection:   Error, dumping error stack:  
Mar  1 16:42:24 - p2p.connection:     Tezos_stdlib__Lwt_pipe.Closed  
Mar  1 16:42:24 - p2p.connection:     IO error: connection with a peer is closed.
```

Where does it come from and is it harmful?

Comment: Are you running your node in cloud or not?

Comment: No it is a physical server with a gigabit connection directly to Frankfurt.

Comment: Seeing this as well. @labeo Why would running in the cloud matter?

Comment: For me this started after compiling the latest version announced on Feb 26th

Comment: I'm observing the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nothing harmful, this message just makes visible a peer disconnection that was formerly only printed in debug mode, and will probably be only visible in debug mode in the future.

And it's normal to be disconnected from peers on a regular basis. It is part of the "connection diversification" process: sometimes a node choose to accept a new incoming connection and close an established one.

#### Technical details:

The error occurs when trying to send data to a disconnected peer.
 It is caught in p2p_socket.ml line 485 while it was formerly on line 480.

The only difference between the two cases is the log message and its logging level.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess if the node is still running every error is not that problematic

Comment: Yes, it is normal  to be disconnected from peers on a regular basis. It is part of the "connection diversification" process: sometimes a node choose to accept a new incoming connection and close an established one.